# Add icons to wordpress menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some problems with Wordpress.. I tried to add icons from Wordpress -> Appearance -> Menu and it works but they are not clickable. I also want to remove the text from the menu icon and add it to "data-tooltip". And the last question is: How to add the menu item icons in a different element (not the "li" element) for example "span"?

My code should be:

```
<ul class="clear-list">
   <li>
      <a href="index.php" data-tooltip="Home"><span class="crt-icon crt-icon-home"></span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="portfolio.php" data-tooltip="Portfolio"><span class="crt-icon crt-icon-portfolio"></span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="testimonials.php" data-tooltip="Testimonials"><span class="crt-icon crt-icon-references"></span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="contact.php" data-tooltip="Contact"><span class="crt-icon crt-icon-contact"></span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But it actually looks like:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="clear-list">
   <li id="menu-item-60" class="crt-icon crt-icon-home menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-60"><a href="......." aria-current="page">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href=".........">Experience</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54"><a href=".......">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58"><a href=".........">Testimonials</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href=".........">Contacts</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I hope you can help me! :)

Comment: Why don't you simply add a code snippet/div and input your custom code that works well?

Answer (score -1):

**Add icons**: easiest way is to add icons via CSS.
You can to add class for each link in admin and to add icon as pseudo-element, for example if your icon is image:

```
.crt-icon a:after {
  background: url(https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-contact-512.png);
  background-size: cover;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

If your icon is font-family - you can add it in 'content' CSS rule.

**Add tooltip and remove text**: you can do it with jquery:

```
$( '#menu-main-menu a' ).each( function () {
  $( this ).attr( 'data-tooltip', $( this ).text() ).empty();
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thats just half the answer

Comment: you are right, I did not noticed other questions...))

Comment: Didn't work.. no one. I want to use the icon from Wordpress -> Appearance -> Menu -> Additional CSS classes (there I write the icon class). So the question is: How to get the icon from there and paste it in "span" tag like in the example "<a href="index.php" data-tooltip="Home"><span class="crt-icon crt-icon-home"></span></a>"

Comment: I guess you did something wrong - I tested all works, pls see attached (btw - I updated a bit answer).
"How to get the icon from there and paste it in "span" tag like in the example" - that's is not simple task, so if you don't understand how to do it with css/js... just trust me: with php you won't understand how to do it))

Another thing: could you please attach screenshot like my where I can to see how you applied styles?

Comment: I fixed it with a plugin for adding icons to menu and function to hide text.. I also added some title and used str_replace to replace <a title=" with <a data-tooltip=" and then put the href="...". Thanks for the help!